# Is there a way to center a <textarea> and <div> element in a parent div without using display: flex?

Tags: html, css

I need to center a div element and a textarea element in the same parent div, and I've tried using display: block on the text area, and I still can't center the two elements. I've tried setting the parent div to display: flex, but the whole page overlaps when I do this. Any solutions for this problem? Here's the code:

```css
body {
  background: #121212;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Overpass", sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: none;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0.1em auto;
}

.b {
  font-weight: 500;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.i {
  font-style: italic;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #121212;
  border: none;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-20deg, #fc6076 0%, #ff9a44 100%);
}

select {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

 ::selection {
  background: rgba(128, 204, 95, 0.5);
}

-moz-::selection {
  background: rgba(128, 204, 95, 0.5);
}

.body {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(7, 7, 7, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgb(7, 7, 7);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Overpass Mono', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0.5vw auto;
}

a.inline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

select:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
}

a.b {
  padding: 0px;
}

.fullloader {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0%;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0ba360 0%, #3cba92 100%);
}

.body::selection {
  background: rgba(82, 83, 170, 0.5);
}

-moz-.body::selection {
  background: rgba(82, 83, 170, 0.5);
}

textarea:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

.button:hover,
input:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
}

input {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

div#divhtml {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass+Mono&family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;1,300;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>

<div style='height:42vw;padding:10px;max-width:725px;margin:0.01em auto;text-align:center;justify-content:center;'>

  <textarea id='txthtml' rows='15' style='width:85vw;height:40vw;max-width:725px;'></textarea><br>
  
  <div style='border-radius:5px;width:85vw;max-width:725px;margin:0.01em auto;overflow:none;'>
    <div id='divhtml' class='body' style='width:inherit;max-width:725px;background:#888888;padding:5px;overflow:auto;margin:0.01em auto;height:50vw;'>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  
  <div style='text-align:left;max-width:725px;margin:0.01em auto;'>
    <div style='position:inherit;'>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent at lacus laoreet, ultricies mi gravida, auctor mi. Maecenas sed malesuada magna. Donec vitae placerat quam, eu auctor metus. Aenean sit amet porttitor dolor. Suspendisse ligula mauris, lobortis sed laoreet vel, auctor ut diam. Aenean consequat eget metus at gravida. Suspendisse laoreet sem a vestibulum fermentum.<br><br>Ut ornare, tortor nec imperdiet pulvinar, erat enim sollicitudin orci, ut sollicitudin lectus dolor ac odio. Nullam eros ex, sollicitudin eu lacinia ac, vehicula non sapien. Quisque et odio eget erat pharetra placerat non at tortor. Vestibulum eu gravida justo. Integer auctor turpis vitae augue finibus volutpat. In vitae mollis leo, in facilisis neque. Donec viverra ex leo. Donec facilisis at purus ullamcorper vulputate. Nam a turpis ac leo tincidunt volutpat a et metus.</span>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: isn't everything centered right now?

Comment: Mostly, but the div is slightly off centered, and I'm looking to fix this problem.

Comment: Which div? the one with the dummy text?, please be more specific. Also, some of your items has a width on it and some don't. If the dummy text div also have the 85vw as width, it would be centered right now

Comment: @Huangism I think the OP is taking about the grey `<div>`. It seems to be to the right a bit when you are NOT in fullscreen.

Comment: Yeah, the grey `<div>` is slightly off, and ideally it should be exactly in line with the `<textarea>`.

Comment: Then remove `width: inherit;` from the grey div

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;` to textarea (to everything)

Comment: Both of these helped me. Thank you so much!

Comment: The div is off-centered on the *screen* because of the scrollbar. It *is* centered on the *page*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This solution was provided by Temani Afif in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711681/is-there-a-way-to-center-a-textarea-and-div-element-in-a-parent-div-without#comment107416311_60711681)*.

You need to apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `.body` `<div>` and to the `textarea`.

---

**Modified Code**

```css
body {
  background: #121212;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Overpass", sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: none;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0.1em auto;
}

.b {
  font-weight: 500;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.i {
  font-style: italic;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #121212;
  border: none;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-20deg, #fc6076 0%, #ff9a44 100%);
}

select {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

 ::selection {
  background: rgba(128, 204, 95, 0.5);
}

-moz-::selection {
  background: rgba(128, 204, 95, 0.5);
}

.body {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(7, 7, 7, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgb(7, 7, 7);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Overpass Mono', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0.5vw auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a.inline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

select:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
}

a.b {
  padding: 0px;
}

.fullloader {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0%;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0ba360 0%, #3cba92 100%);
}

.body::selection {
  background: rgba(82, 83, 170, 0.5);
}

-moz-.body::selection {
  background: rgba(82, 83, 170, 0.5);
}

textarea:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

.button:hover,
input:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
}

input {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

div#divhtml {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass+Mono&family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;1,300;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>

<div style='height:42vw;padding:10px;max-width:725px;margin:0.01em auto;text-align:center;justify-content:center;'>

  <textarea id='txthtml' rows='15' style='width:85vw;height:40vw;max-width:725px;'></textarea><br>

  <div style='border-radius:5px;width:85vw;max-width:725px;margin:0.05vw auto;overflow:none;'>
    <div id='divhtml' class='body' style='width:inherit;max-width:725px;background:#888888;padding:5px;overflow:auto;margin:0.01em auto;height:50vw;'>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div style='text-align:left;max-width:725px;margin:0.01em auto;'>
    <div style='position:inherit;'>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent at lacus laoreet, ultricies mi gravida, auctor mi. Maecenas sed malesuada magna. Donec vitae placerat quam, eu auctor metus. Aenean sit amet porttitor dolor. Suspendisse ligula mauris, lobortis sed laoreet vel, auctor ut diam. Aenean consequat eget metus at gravida. Suspendisse laoreet sem a vestibulum fermentum.<br><br>Ut ornare, tortor nec imperdiet pulvinar, erat enim sollicitudin orci, ut sollicitudin lectus dolor ac odio. Nullam eros ex, sollicitudin eu lacinia ac, vehicula non sapien. Quisque et odio eget erat pharetra placerat non at tortor. Vestibulum eu gravida justo. Integer auctor turpis vitae augue finibus volutpat. In vitae mollis leo, in facilisis neque. Donec viverra ex leo. Donec facilisis at purus ullamcorper vulputate. Nam a turpis ac leo tincidunt volutpat a et metus.</span>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When copying the answer from someone in the comments, instead you should make your answer Community Wiki rather than asking people to upvote a comment. Comments are ephemeral and eventually get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

With all of your help, I compiled a working version of this:

```css
body {
  background: #121212;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Overpass", sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: none;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0.1em auto;
}

.b {
  font-weight: 500;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.i {
  font-style: italic;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #121212;
  border: none;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-20deg, #fc6076 0%, #ff9a44 100%);
}

select {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

 ::selection {
  background: rgba(128, 204, 95, 0.5);
}

-moz-::selection {
  background: rgba(128, 204, 95, 0.5);
}

.body {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(7, 7, 7, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgb(7, 7, 7);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Overpass Mono', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0.5vw auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a.inline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

select:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
}

a.b {
  padding: 0px;
}

.fullloader {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0%;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0ba360 0%, #3cba92 100%);
}

.body::selection {
  background: rgba(82, 83, 170, 0.5);
}

-moz-.body::selection {
  background: rgba(82, 83, 170, 0.5);
}

textarea:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

.button:hover,
input:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
}

input {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

div#divhtml {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass+Mono&family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;1,300;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>

<div style='height:42vw;padding:10px;max-width:725px;margin:0.01em auto;text-align:center;justify-content:center;'>

  <textarea id='txthtml' rows='15' style='width:85vw;height:40vw;max-width:725px;'></textarea><br>

  <div style='border-radius:5px;width:85vw;max-width:725px;margin:0.05vw auto;overflow:none;'>
    <div id='divhtml' class='body' style='max-width:725px;background:#888888;padding:5px;overflow:auto;margin:0.01em auto;height:50vw;'>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div style='text-align:left;max-width:725px;margin:0.01em auto;'>
    <div style='position:inherit;'>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent at lacus laoreet, ultricies mi gravida, auctor mi. Maecenas sed malesuada magna. Donec vitae placerat quam, eu auctor metus. Aenean sit amet porttitor dolor. Suspendisse ligula mauris, lobortis sed laoreet vel, auctor ut diam. Aenean consequat eget metus at gravida. Suspendisse laoreet sem a vestibulum fermentum.<br><br>Ut ornare, tortor nec imperdiet pulvinar, erat enim sollicitudin orci, ut sollicitudin lectus dolor ac odio. Nullam eros ex, sollicitudin eu lacinia ac, vehicula non sapien. Quisque et odio eget erat pharetra placerat non at tortor. Vestibulum eu gravida justo. Integer auctor turpis vitae augue finibus volutpat. In vitae mollis leo, in facilisis neque. Donec viverra ex leo. Donec facilisis at purus ullamcorper vulputate. Nam a turpis ac leo tincidunt volutpat a et metus.</span>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```